# VB.NET Executing PowerShell Script

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am currently trying to run a PowerShell script from VB.NET. If I run the script directly from a PowerShell window I open in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe then the script runs absoloutely fine.

However, when I run it from VB.NET using the following command

```vb
Dim LoggedInUsers As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-noexit C:\LoggedInUsers\CurrentLoggedOnServers.ps1")

Process.Start(LoggedinUsers)
```

The PowerShell console will say that the term query is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

I am trying to run a script the contains this.

```cs
$username = 'User1'
$Path = 'C:\Folder1\ServerLoginStatus\'
$servers = Get-Content C:\Folder1\ServerList.txt
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $servernamepath = $path + $server + '.txt'
    query user /server:$server | Out-File $servernamepath
}
```

Do I have to import a specific module or function to use this cmdlet?

Comment: `query user` is not a powershell command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

Comment: Please show the exact code and error message, not "something similar".

Comment: I have now put in the code as asked for. thanks

Comment: @sadowillow then how come it runs when I open powershell directly? Yet wont when opened via a VB.net powershell window?

Comment: Might be a path issue. Try `${env:windir}\system32\query.exe user ...`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Nope, unfortunately not a directory issue. CD to that location and run the same command, get the same issue.

Comment: Try `Test-Path 'C:\windows\system32\query.exe'` in the script run by your VB.net program. What does that give you?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers when I test the path it says false, but it's 100% there. I then chance query.exe to cmd.exe and it says true. Is there any reason as to why it wouldn't be able to see it? When I run in a normal powershell window with no admin credentials it can see it. Why is the vb.net powershell generated window any different? Thanks!